# Modifying NewForm without SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2010, edit-form, sharepoint-designer

I want to customize the EditForm.aspx of a list but SharePoint Designer is disabled on this site collection. What is the best way to modify EditForm if I can't access it through SPD?

Comment: You could try using jquery script in a content editor placed on the newform.aspx. That'll be helpful for UI related modifications

Comment: good idea i'll try it

Comment: In addition to approach suggested by , @Abhishek you can also try customizing form in Infopath if Infopath Designer is available.

Comment: I've used this successfully in the past http://www.markrackley.net/2013/08/29/easy-custom-layouts-for-default-sharepoint-forms/